Ref conditional typescript type narrowing based on another variable
I'm trying to create a boolean ref called isLoggedIn that I can use to narrow my user ref's type. I can't get typescript to stop complaining. I think this is possible with typescript conditional types. Is this a issue with the ref not being unwrapped?
Playground
test.ts

import { ref } from 'vue'

type User = {
  id: number;
  email: string;
};

const user = ref<User | null>(null);
type IsLoggedInType = typeof user.value extends User ? true : false;
const isLoggedIn = ref<IsLoggedInType>(false);

export {
  user, 
  isLoggedIn
}


// Attempt 2
// const user = ref<User | null>(null);
// type IsLoggedInType<T extends User | null> = T extends User ? true : false;
// const isLoggedIn = ref<IsLoggedInType<typeof user.value>>(false);


// Attempt 3 - Invert 
// type IsLoggedInType = typeof user.value extends null ? false : true;


App.vue
<script setup>
import { user, isLoggedIn } from './test.ts';


if(isLoggedIn.value === false){
  console.log(user.value.id + 1);
}

</script>





This is not possible with just a type because it is not known until runtime whether user is null or not. You can use a function to do it:
function isLoggedIn(user: User | null): user is User {
  return user !== null;
}

const user = ref<User | null>(null).value;
if (isLoggedIn(user)) {
  console.log(user.id + 1);
}

Or, in this case just do a null check:
const user = ref<User | null>(null).value;
if (user) {
  console.log(user.id + 1);
}


Yeah I understand that it is not possible to know if the user is null until runtime, but I should be able to narrow the possibilities to get the correct type right? E.G User can be null or user. E.G user !== null && user.email = 'new value'. I want to basically do this, but I want isLoggedIn to be the thing doing the type narrowing of the user.

There are limits to what the compiler can infer from context. If you have something like foo: { which: 'a'; value: string; } | { which: 'b'; value: number; } then this code: if (foo.which === 'a') {  } will narrow the type of foo and accessing foo.value will give you the type string, but there are limits to how deep the compiler goes with this type of thing.
